# $\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm d x^n} e^{-\frac {1}{x^2}} = 0$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

This is an exercise from David Brannan's Mathematical Analysis. I've proved parts (a) - (c) but need help with Part (d). Any guidance appreciated.

[image]

### EDIT

I have solved it, by induction using the results of parts (a) and (c).

Comment: That is too much irrelevant details, I did not delete them, I leave it to you to decide what to keep. please make the titles as specific as possible to the question

Comment: This is an abuse of notation. What you have if $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$. Prove by induction that $f^{(n)}(x)=P_n(x)e^{-1/x^2}/x^{3n}$ for some polynomial $P_n(x)$ for all $n$ and all $x\neq 0$. Then let $x$ tend to $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure why the author is having you chase the degree of the polynomial in b and c. You don't need it to conclude for d; maybe that's what's throwing you off. You just need that it's some polynomial in 1/x.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: What is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^n}$$ for any $n\geq0$?

Comment: i think you want $e^{-1/x^2}$ there.

Comment: @Avatar: Fixed. Thanks.